# What's the oldest supported program for Linux?

Tags: linux, compatibility

How far back does Linux's backwards compatibility extend?

Comment: Are you asking about source ([API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)) compatibility or binary ([ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)) compatibility?

Comment: Hello World. --

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_%28computer_program%29), `dc` is older than the C programming language.

[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) indicates that `roff`, which evolved into `troff` dates back to about 1970 -- but it says it was *added* to Unix, implying that other programs already existed.  It mentions the text editor, probably `ed`.

One could argue that `/bin/true` is a reimplementation of [`IEFBR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEFBR14) from IBM's OS/360.